# in NetworkX draw the graph dividing the plot area in 3

Tags: python, graph, draw, networkx

I have a graph in Networkx with different info inside. The graph nodes look like this:

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(shape1, level=1)
G.add_node(shape2, level=2)
G.add_node(shape3, level=2)
G.add_node(shape4, level=3)
...
```

I want to draw the graph in order to have all the shapes at level 1 at the top of the plot, all the shapes in level 3 positioned in the lower part of the plot and all the shapes at level 2 in the middle. There are maximum 3 levels.

I have been reading documentations from NetworkX, but till now I used only this random positioning of the nodes:

`pos = nx.spring_layout(G) 
nx.draw(G, pos)`.

Do you know any smarter way to position the nodes of the graph as I want?

P.S.: The desired output would be roughly like this:
[image]

I don't need to draw also the lines for dividing the levels, I just put them to make it clear what I need.

Comment: What does "don't formalize on the edges" mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The layout "dot" provided the interface to [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) seems to do what you are looking for. While it works for this simple graph you've provided, you may need to tweak the output for larger more complicated graphs.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_node(1,level=1)
G.add_node(2,level=2)
G.add_node(3,level=2)
G.add_node(4,level=3)

G.add_edge(1,2)
G.add_edge(1,3)
G.add_edge(2,4)

import pylab as plt
nx.draw_graphviz(G, node_size=1600, cmap=plt.cm.Blues,
                 node_color=range(len(G)),
                 prog='dot')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer for NetworkX 2.6.2:

```py
pos = nx.nx_pydot.graphviz_layout(G, prog="dot")
nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, font_weight='bold')
plt.show()
```

(make sure you have `pydot` installed)